# Installing R packages for old R version without sudo privelages

Tags: r

I am running on a computer without sudo privileges with R version 2.13.1 installed, and I want to install a package (Rcpp).  If I try to install the package via install.packages()

I get

```
 package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

I think because by default in CRAN requires R version 2.15 and up.

I can't update my R version as I'm not superuser. Is there anyway way (without sudo) to install and old version of Rcpp for my old R version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just install from source? You can download the older versions of `Rccp` from the [package archive](http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/).

Read the help file (`?install.packages`) for instructions, but basically you provide the path to the downloaded package and set `repos` to `NULL`. You may also need to specify a different `lib` path if you don't have sufficient privileges to install to the default R library.

I have not tried it, but you may also want to try [this function](https://gist.github.com/1503736) which lets you specify the version of a package you want to install.